# Python: I get an Error at creating a bot for Instagram, how can I fix this?

Tags: python

Hello I tryed for a few time, to fix this but I cannot find it out. Maybe sombody can help me. I want to create a Bot for Instagram. I hope this informations could help for answering my question.

```
    def __init__(self, username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe")
    def WaitForObject(self, type, string):
        return WebDriverWait(self.browser,3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((type,string)))

    def WaitForObject(self, type, string):
        return WebDriverWait(self.browser,3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((type,string)))

    def login(self):
        self.browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/")


        login_objects = self.WaitForObject(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input._2hvTZ.pexuQ.zyHYP")

        login_objects[0].send_keys(self.username)
        login_objects[1].send_keys(self.password)
        login_objects[1].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        fenster = self.WaitForObject(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.aOOlW.HoLwm").click()
        fenster2 = self.WaitForObject(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.aOOlW.bIiDR").click()

Bot = InstagramBot("XXX","XXX")

Bot.login()
```

Here is my error:

```
line 31, in login
    fenster = self.WaitForObject(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.aOOlW.HoLwm").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Anybody know why I get this, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's multiple elements with the CCS_Selector `button.aOOlW.HoLwm` on the website. That's why it errors out saying there's a list.

```py
print(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.aOOlW.HoLwm'))
```

should list all found elements, with that specific css selector. To fix the error you're getting. you will need to be more specific, adressing the element. For example choosing it out of the list and getting it's specific attributes.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html